# Sever 2008 how to block income by computer name

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have someone trying to remote into my network using my username. Keeps locking my account out. I have the computer name from Event Properties but not an IP address. Everything I found wants an IP address I do not have.

Comment: Is this an internal computer? Do you have the port they are trying to use? You will probably have to approach this from the firewall.

Comment: you could ping the computer name and try and find the ip address through the computer name in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

The question is difficult because there really isn't enough information, but I'll give it a stab.

If the connection is from the public internet (a really really bad idea giving direct or even NAT connection to RDP on your server), you will need a computer name and a domain name to potentially locate the IP address.  If you don't see a domain name, you will have no idea who is connecting.  Your firewall or router may have a log of the incoming IP address.

Things I don't know:
Home or a business.
Administrator or user account.
NAT behind a router, direct connection or through a VPN.

Assuming internet connectivity and you having some consumer grade router with a Network Address Translation (NAT) so your server isn't on the public internet and that the account being locked out is Administrator.

My recommendations:

- Review firewall logs.  If the firewall logs cannot show connection information, I recommend disposing of the firewall/router and replacing it.
- Consider using a true firewall.  Even a free one like IPCop.
- Disable NAT and use a VPN client to access the
  network remotely.
- If you HAVE to use a NAT, change the port that is
  used on the public side.
- Never use the administrator account.  Create
  another with a different name and disable the administrator account.
- Install Wireshark on your server to see what traffic is hitting your server, from where (but if not on the same network, traffic will be coming from the router).  You can filter on the protocol.